# javascript selector for item when next is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a list of nodes

```
A
B
B
A
A
A
B
B
```

I want a selector querySelector or function that will match all `A` items where they are followed by a visible `B` item.

jQuery has a `$(".a ~ .b:visible")` except this returns a list of the `.b` selectors and I want the `.a`. And it's jQuery, not pure javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use combination of `:has()` and `+` adjacent sibling selector.

```js
$('.a:has(+ .b:visible)').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b" style="display: none;">B</div>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b" style="display: none;">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```

Or you can select `.b:visible` and then `prev(.a)` element.

```js
$('.b:visible').prev('.a').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b" style="display: none;">B</div>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b" style="display: none;">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```

Comment: aah, nice, I didn't think of using :has

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the .next() method?

```
var list
$(".a")each(function(index, obj)  {
   if($(obj).next().is(":visible")) {
      list += obj
   }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is easier way to do that:

```
$('.a + .b:visible').prev()
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but consider a case where you have more than 1 such pair. Not `$()` will return a list of jQuery objects and `.prev` would fail